# GregorianCalendar setFirstDayOfWeek not affecting WEEK_OF_YEAR on pre Nougat

Tags: android, dayofweek, gregorian-calendar, week-number

The code below gives a different result on Nougat and pre-Nougat. Take a look and try it yourself if you want. I would appreciate it if someone could explain me why and give a solution.

I want the correct WEEK_OF_YEAR value, dependent on the first day of the week, on all Android versions. I have a time sheet app and i'm using the gregorianCalendar a lot, so I don't feel like switching to another class/lib.

```
    //default first day of the week is Monday for replication. I live in the Netherlands, it's weird.
    Locale l = new Locale("nl", "NL");

    GregorianCalendar test = new GregorianCalendar(l);
    test.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2017);
    test.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
    test.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 29);//this is a Sunday

    int week = test.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);//should be 4
    test.setFirstDayOfWeek(1);//Set it to Sunday
    int week2 = test.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);//should be 5 but is 4 below nougat???
```

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I don't think my answer is going to be that useful to you now apart from the general nod in the direction of the problem (Nougat matching app and system locale). To attract better answers, perhaps you can clarify something more. Is setting Locale in your sample code just to replicate the problem or is it something you would like to do inside your app?

Comment: Thanks anyway. The Locale is just to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the [release notes for Nougat](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support.html) you can see that there is enhanced support for Locales.

Especially,

> Prior to Android 7.0, Android could not always successfully match app and system locales.

I too have noticed this on my own device. My phone is set with English (Australia) Locale. Prior to Nougat,

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd MMMM").print(new LocalDate(2017,1,29));
```

would print `29 Jan` (no full-stop/period) but after Nougat it prints `29 Jan.` (with period).

Although it's hard for me to give exact specifics, it seems as if this is what is happening in your case. Post-Nougat, the phone is able to better match the app and system locales, including the first day of the week for your Locale. In any case, stepping through with the debugger to find the root cause won't work because the call is handled inside `libcore`, rather than a Java class exposed in the source code.

If an Android device is incorrectly reporting the first day of year/first week of year, there would be little you can do besides work around it:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 24) {
    //pre-Nougat logic
}
else {
    //Nougat/post-Nougat logic
}
```

You could also perhaps try using the [enhanced replacement for GregorianCalendar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/util/GregorianCalendar.html) (added in SDK 24) to fix your problem.

If you use classes like [Joda-time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or use the new [JSR-310](http://www.threeten.org/) classes (through the ThreeTen backport) you might be able to get what you want without having to work around `GregorianCalendar`. In general these classes are much easier to use and less bug-prone. Many developers have already given up on `java.util.Calendar` and `java.util.Date` because of issues like this. Please see the answers [to this canonical question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442/5241933) for details

If you were to use Joda, you can use `LocalDate.fromCalendarFields(test)` to convert your `GregorianCalendar` object into a `LocalDate`. These classes use the ISO standard where the first day of week is always Monday. You would then write the logic you want on top of them. Then the issue with `GregorianCalendar` would be "isolated" into a mere issue with retrieving the first week of the year for a given Locale. If your app incorporates calls to a server, you could serve the first day of week from an API call instead.

**Update:**

Note timezone behaviour has been updated in [Android O](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations.html#thread-annotations):

Additional locale and internationalization-related changes are as follows:

> Time zone name parsing has changed. Previously, Android devices used the system clock value sampled at boot time to cache the time zone names used for parsing date times. As a result, parsing could be negatively affected if the system clock was wrong at boot time or in other, rarer cases.
>   Now, in common cases the parsing logic uses ICU and the current system clock value when parsing time zone names. This change provides more correct results, which may differ from earlier Android versions when your app uses classes like SimpleDateFormat. Android O updates the version of ICU to version 58.

Comment: Basically I want the correct WEEK_OF_YEAR value, dependent on the first day of the week, on all Android versions. I have a timehseet app and i'm using the gregorianCalendar a lot, so I don't feel like switching to another class/lib.

Answer (score -1):

From what I think the issue lies in the line where you are setting the month.

//Here in the month Parameter you are passing 0 as the value which might be creating the problem because even though the array starts from 0 the Input that this Calendar.MONTH accepts is between 1 to 12. So try changing that.

Or You can also change it to this for setting it to January as the month use

```
test.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
```

// Also here in this line try and change to

```
test.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.SUNDAY);//Set it to Sunday
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: I'm sorry buddy, this is not true. The value of `Calendar.JANUARY` is also 0.

Comment: The only reason I am telling to use Calendar.JANUARY is that if suppose the value of the JANUARY changes from 0 to some other value then your code wont be needed to get updated.